# Update Workflow of a Sitecore form Item

Tags: sitecore-forms, workflow

In sitecore I have created a Sitecore form in Sitecore FormBuilder and saved it as template. I have added default Workflow in Form Template standard value.

I have published this Form saved as template and so it is in published state now(Initially it was in draft state).

The issue faced is:

Whenever I create a new Form in Sitecore FormBuilder based on this template, it also inherits the published workflow state. The requirement is whenever a new form is created it should be in draft state of the default workflow.
Please suggest to make this change.

I tried by adding a handler  in the OnVersionAdded and OnItemCreating but, the EventArgs does not pick the current form id it picks something named system with different id.

Comment: Can you create a copy of that template form which is published now and make a template from the copy? And set its state to "draft"?

Comment: Suggestion is to always keep the template in draft state?? In the content editor if i duplicate the template or any other form it will be in draft state, but if i create a new form from the template in Formbuilder then it always set to the published state.

Comment: To alter default save form action that executes in form builder, you may need to look into:  Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client.Pipelines.SaveForm pipeline. See, Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Pipelines.Client.config